# Replace NA with interpolated value for specific column fields in r

Tags: r, interpolation, na

I have a timeseries data with NA values in few specific column fields. I am getting an error while trying to replace NAs in column fields with interpolated values. Below is a sample code that I am trying to execute with the error message below. The first row has a value of 17.58 (temperature) and the next value is only at row 30 (2 minute time step) with a value of 16.58. This pattern of NAs and data availability extends for rest of the data.

```
library(zoo)
my_data[, 42] <- na.approx(my_data[, 42])
```

Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, , 42, value = c(17.58, 17.5466666666667,  :
replacement has 120726 rows, data has 132373

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is specified in the `?na.approx`

> An object of similar structure as object with NAs replaced by interpolation. For na.approx **only the internal NAs are replaced** and leading or trailing NAs are omitted if na.rm = TRUE or not replaced if na.rm = FALSE.

By default, the `na.approx` uses `na.rm = TRUE`

> na.approx(object, x = index(object), xout, ..., na.rm = TRUE, maxgap = Inf, along)

---

Thus, we can change the code to

```
my_data[, 42] <- na.approx(my_data[, 42], na.rm = FALSE)
```

In a large dataset, it is possible to have leading/lagging NAs and using the OP's code results in an output vector with less number of elements as `na.rm = TRUE`, which triggers the length difference error in replacement

Comment: When I try extending it to other columns within the dataframe I'm getting an error. There are in total 49 columns in the data frame.
my_data[, 42:47, 49] <- na.approx(my_data[, 42:47, 49], na.rm = FALSE)
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, , 42:47, 49, value = c(NA, NA, NA,  : 
  unused argument (49)

Comment: @AravindanKalai what is the eror.  Your vector is not correct i.e. it should be `c(42:47, 49)`

Comment: Error in [<-.data.frame(*tmp*, , 42:47, 49, value = c(NA, NA, NA, : unused argument (49)

Comment: @AravindanKalai I updated the comment.  You are passing the column index, and it should be a single vector i.e. `c(42:47, 49)` instead of variadic argument

Comment: i.e. you can check the usage of `?Extract` `x[i, j, ... , drop = TRUE]` the `j` is the column index.  if you pass two or more arguments, it goes to the variadic component `...` which is for a different use

Answer (score 0):

perhaps we can use `approxfun` if you need linear interpolation, for example

```
> y <- c(17.58, rep(NA, 28), 16.58)

> approxfun(which(!is.na(y)), na.omit(y))(seq_along(y))
 [1] 17.58000 17.54552 17.51103 17.47655 17.44207 17.40759 17.37310 17.33862
 [9] 17.30414 17.26966 17.23517 17.20069 17.16621 17.13172 17.09724 17.06276
[17] 17.02828 16.99379 16.95931 16.92483 16.89034 16.85586 16.82138 16.78690
[25] 16.75241 16.71793 16.68345 16.64897 16.61448 16.58000
```